# Swift tableView and prepareForSegue functions

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get the `tableView` function to change the row before it goes into the `prepareForSegue` function. Below are the two functions:

1. This function is called when a cell is clicked and it changes the row variable to the current row that is clicked

   ```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
                           didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
       row = indexPath.row
       NSLog("You selected cell number: \(indexPath.row)!")
   }
   ```
2. This function is for the segue from the cell that is clicked to the next window

   ```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
       var destViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondView

       destViewController.nameString = namesArray[getRow()]
   }
   ```

Comment: don't try and explain your problem in the title. Write your question first in the body (along with properly formatted code), and then give it a title that summarises your overall problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the `getRow()` method is, but it looks like you should just directly use your global `row` variable.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var destViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondView

    destViewController.nameString = namesArray[row] // use your global variable row here
}
```